# Entity Framework does not update child entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 in a Windows Forms project. The application has 5 layers in class library projects (DesktopUI, Logic, Entities, Common, DataAccess).

I can create or delete entities using EF correctly, but, when I try to update them, the child entity doesn't update.

Here's the update code:

```
public async Task Update(Phone entity)
{
        using (_context = new PhonesContext())
        {
            _context.Entry(entity.Cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.Entry(entity.Modelo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
}
```

Any advice?

Thanks!!

Comment: Unless you have tracking disabled, you won't need to do this. Just update the fields and call _context.SaveChangesAsync(). The problem is not in the piece of code you have included. It would be better if you show how entity is filled and how the tables are related in the database (DbModel). It seems that relations are invalid or missing.

Comment: Noting obviously wrong here, what makes you conclude that the update doesn't come through?